# Automatic Resizing in Irfanview

Tags: images, irfanview

Is there a setting to enable Irfanview to open a large imaze to fit your desktop? It's annoying browsing through an SD card and having to manually resize them so you can see what the photo looks like.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to `View > Display Options (window mode)` and select `Fit images to Window` or `Fit Only big images to window`.

If you maximize the IrfanView window, the first option (`Fit images to Window`) should suffice. This will scale up smaller images, and scale down the larger ones.

If you keep IrfanView windowed, then the second option will only rescale images that are larger than the IrfanView window. Images that are smaller will display at their native resolution.

Comment: D00d... I've lived with this problem for about 10 years :D thanks

Comment: It should be a capital crime to not ship this software with 'fit to window' by default.

Comment: @scott You may wish to add the two suggestions in my long ago answer to yours. Yours and most on web answers relate to full screen situations. You suggest that the "only big images" may work non full screen but as of October 2023 it does not do so for me. My two answers relate to windowed non full screen mode and work as stated. I had this problem NOW and found my old answer to fix it :-). Need to make better notes. :-(

Answer (score 0):

What Scott said, and:

- Shift-W will select fit image to Window in no-fullscreen mode.
- Ctrl-H will display image at full size (pixel per pixel) in non-fullscreen mode.

The above are extremely useful when editing - allowing either overall view or detailed close-up.

Comment: Here I am 7.6 years on finding my own answer as an answer to my current problem !!! :-). I could find this simple answer nowhere else. This answer deserves at least 100 ipvotes :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 0):

To maximize large an image to fit your desktop just double click it. (ESC brings it back to where it was.)

Then, like it it's regular window:
...Spacebar will take it to the next image in that directory
...arrow keys or L & R mouse buttons to see the next or previous image in that directory.
... + and - magnifying glass tool enlarges and shrinks image.
and much more.

*(Here I am, answering a 9 1/3 year old question!)*